# AngularJS DataTable não carrega os dados da tabela quando uso uma váriavel no título de uma coluna

Tags: angularjs, datatable

Olá, estou usando o angularJS DataTable https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/archives/#!/changeOptions. Preciso que o título de uma coluna seja dinâmico, usando uma variável nele. Porém quando faço isso, ao tentar atualizar os dados da tabela ela não atualiza, mesmo a requisição (no network do Chrome) estando trazendo todos os dados corretamente. A tabela só atualiza com os dados atuais se mudar o "resultados por página".

Para deixar o título da coluna dinâmico estou definindo o **dtColumns** novamente sempre que a variável muda e colocando ela na função **withTitle()** dessa maneira **withTitle(variableName)**

Portanto, a definição das colunas ficou assim:

```
vm.dtColumns = [
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('id').withTitle('ID'),
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('firstName').withTitle('First name'),
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('lastName').withTitle('Last name').notSortable()
    ];
```

E a mudança do título da coluna específica ficou assim:

```
function changeColumns(variableName) {
        vm.dtColumns = [
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('id').withTitle('ID'),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('firstName').withTitle(variableName),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('lastName').withTitle('Last name').notSortable()
        ];
    }
```

Se no lugar de **variableName** eu coloco o mesmo nome no qual a coluna foi definida, a tabela funciona normalmente.